# How do the timing attacks works and why Symfony's string utils suggest a precise order in passing strings to compare

Tags: php, security, symfony, passwords, string-comparison

To compare the hashed password with the one provided by the user there is the util `StringUtil`provided by the Symfony.

The documentation speaks about the "timing attacks": an attacker may have useful information about the complexity of the password observing the time needed to a website to compare the provided password with the one it stores.

The [documentation says](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/secure_tools.html#comparing-strings) also that

> To avoid timing attacks, the known string must be the first argument
>   and the user-entered string the second.

Why does the order matter?

Comment: Did you try a Google search? Gave me pretty good results.

Comment: Yes, did and understood the base dynamics of a timing attack. Which key did you used?

Comment: "Timing attack" :) A good PHP specific resource is http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/11/its-all-about-time.html

Comment: It's really a complex topic O.O Anyway, I don't yet understand why an inversion of strings (pass first the safe-string and then the user-string) makes the comparison secure. This is the point: why does the order matter?

Comment: @Aerendir It doesn't. Sorry for the confusion, I should have thought about updating the documentation when I was discussing a fix for this earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the current version of `StringUtils`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/7f745d72c004dc37572bb57cb772df1f2d8ac146/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Util/StringUtils.php#L28-L69), it actually doesn't matter. What does matter is the correct order of, e.g. `password_verify()`.

The documentation is likely referring to the [2014 and earlier version of `StringUtils`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/83c15db887fd1f614716ea2de5853ac84054d604/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Util/StringUtils.php#L28-L65), which tried to avoid leaking the string length. During the discussion to [harden this class against mbstring.func_overload configuration](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/14028), it was decided that leaking length was unavoidable, the string length is usually public (i.e. for a MAC), and it's generally better to focus on stopping the leak of useful information.

In that case, the order used to matter, but now it really doesn't.

I'd call it an outdated documentation issue. I [opened a ticked in symfony-docs](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/5618) to correct it.